# python code not executing, even after syntax being correct

Tags: python

I have written a simple python code to take in an input and using that input should perform some function declarations but it doesn't show me the expected result. Here is the code:

```
start = print('Answer yes or no to continue please')
name = input(str('\nIs this it'))

if name == 'yes':
    def f():
        print('This could be it')

    def do_twice(x, f):

        f = input(str('Are you sure this it'))
        if f == yes:
            print('Ok thank you')
            print('Your input is', f)
else:
    pass
```

Comment: What is the expected result? What do you think this code should do?

Comment: And what do you mean it doesn't show the expected result? It defines 2 functions and never calls either of them, expected result is that it doesn't print anything after taking input

Comment: Please refomat your code input. If this is your full code: you never call the function. Also, did you understand the concept of a function? Some of your code looks really weird to me

Comment: Your syntax maybe correct but what about logic of this code ? There is a lot of confusion after first if.

Comment: Also, on line one, print doesn't return anything (apart from None) so does not need saving into a variable

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you wanted to control your program flow by user input. Try this way :

```
def badinput():
    name = input(str('Answer yes or no to continue please\nIs this it'))

    if name == 'yes':
        print('This could be it ')

        f = input(str('Are you sure this it '))
        if f == 'yes':
            print('Ok thank you.', 'Your input is: ', f)
        else:
            print('Your input s != \'yes\'')

    elif name == 'no':
        print('Ok thank you. Exit.')
    else:
        print('Your input s != \'yes\'')
```

Comment: Thanks for all your comments guys ..I'm just a beginner  so I'm still really new to coding ...I'll read up more

Answer (score 0):

After declaring a function you need to call them, learn about [python function](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions). Don't definition function in **if statement**. I think you code should be looks like:

```
start = print('Answer yes or no to continue please\n') 
answer= input (str('Is this it\n'))

def f(): 
    print ('This could be it\n' )
def do_twice(answer):
    user_input = input (str('Are you sure?\n'))
    if user_input == answer:
        print('Ok thank you\n')
        print ('Your input is ', user_input)

if answer == 'yes': 
    f()
else:
    do_twice(answer)
```